# Text Form Field with Flutter Google Places Auto Complete returning error

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

I am building a Flutter app, and trying to add a Text Form Field with Google Places Auto Complete API, but when I try to build the application, it returns me an error, and I can't fix it.

**I have this code:**

```
import 'package:google_maps_webservice/places.dart';
import 'package:flutter_google_places/flutter_google_places.dart';
import 'package:google_api_headers/google_api_headers.dart';
import 'dart:async';

const kGoogleApiKey = "API_KEY";
String address = '';

Future<Null> displayPrediction(Prediction p) async {
    if (p != null) {
      GoogleMapsPlaces _places = GoogleMapsPlaces(
        apiKey: kGoogleApiKey,
        apiHeaders: await GoogleApiHeaders().getHeaders(),
      );

      PlacesDetailsResponse detail =
          await _places.getDetailsByPlaceId(p.placeId);

      var placeId = p.placeId;
      double lat = detail.result.geometry.location.lat;
      double lng = detail.result.geometry.location.lng;

      var address = detail.result.formattedAddress;
    }
  }

TextFormField(
                            decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(
                              hintText: "Enter Company Address",
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.map),
                            ),
                            onTap: () async {
                              Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
                                  context: context, apiKey: kGoogleApiKey);
                              displayPrediction(p);
                            },
                            validator: (val) =>
                                val.isEmpty ? 'Enter address' : null),
```

When I try to build the project, it returns me the following error:

```
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_webservice-0.0.19/lib/src/utils.dart:61:27: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.
 - 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'.
    return httpClient.get(url, headers: headers);
```

I can't find the problem

Comment: Which version of flutter_google_places plugin do you use?

Comment: I am using this versions: google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.2
 
  flutter_google_places: ^0.2.8
  google_api_headers: ^0.1.1+2
  rxdart: ^0.25.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having researched, I have found that problem is in google_maps_webservice-0.0.19 plugin. In 0.0.19 version, they passed String to Uri and it throw exception.

The issue has been opened :[Issue](https://github.com/lejard-h/google_maps_webservice/issues/105)

How to resolve this problem:

1.You can ask them to resolve this issue.

or

2. You can update google_maps_webservice plugin to google_maps_webservice 0.0.20-nullsafety.3

or

3. You can fork their repository, resolve that bugs and use your forked and resolved github repository in your project

Comment: Also, do you know anything about now loading the places? The code is working, it opens the screen with the search bar and the powered by google logo, but when I type an address, it doesn't show anything

Comment: Sorry, but I did not use this plugin. But I can recommend checking if your token is valid.
If there is API to see response from GOOGLE API, print the response. It may possible that this API has some limitations f.e. after several requests you cannot get location  because your account can in trial mode (I mean you should pay to get places location)

Comment: Yeah, I looked into stackoverflow, most things, my code is correct, and I have an active billing account with the places API enabled, but it just show the loading bar when I type an address, but doesn't show anything for results :/